# Is it possbile to dim the typescript type annotations in vscode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I'm reading a bunch of typescript code at the moment in vscode and to my tastes having the type annotations syntax highlighted the same as the code makes it harder to skim.

I've been trying to adjust the syntax highlighter to dim (or even gray out) the type annotations using vscode.settings, but without too much luck.

Is it possible to achieve a change like shown in the attached image or am I just wasting my time on this?

[image: (above: current syntax highlighting, below: desired highlighting)]

@emeraldsanto suggested this (modified to just apply to all themes)

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "types": "#C0C0C0"
}
```

[image: almost]

But it's only halfway there... is there anything that can be done about the nested types?

{edit 2} Actually it's nowhere near where I wanted to be because this greys out *all* types, even things like `new Promise<>` in the code get greyed out. That's not optional type information but critical code :(

The best I've managed to date is to look at it the other way around and highlight the parameter names in bold.

```
    "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
        "rules": {
            "parameter.declaration": {
                "bold": true
            },
            "interface": "#C0C0C0"
        }
    }
```

I think my conclusion is that what I really want is simply not doable at the moment.

Comment: I've just opened an issue on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/158452 that takes up that idea

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add the following to your VSCode `settings.json`:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "[Verdandi]": {
    "types": "#C0C0C0"
  }
},
```

You will need to replace `Verdandi` with the name of your current theme.

Comment: It's definitely a start, but it only sort of half works. I've updated the original post with the results.  What I'd like is to get the full Promise<...> to be grayed out. Not to mention that the {email:} also stays highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Credits to @Parasomnopolis over at [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/pzqaip/any_vs_code_extension_to_dim_the_typescript/), reproduced here for your convenience (and for quicker reference for googlers that didn't find it there):

> if you are using the `Visual Studio Light` theme, you would put the following in your vscode settings .json file:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations":
{
    "[Visual Studio Light]":
    {
        "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
                "support.type.primitive.ts",
                "entity.name.type.ts",
                "meta.type.tuple.ts",
                "meta.type.annotation.ts",
                "meta.type.parameters.ts",
                "keyword.operator.type.ts",
                "meta.return.type.arrow.ts",
                "keyword.operator.type.annotation.ts",
                "meta.return.type.ts",
                "punctuation.definition.typeparameters.begin.ts",
                "punctuation.definition.typeparameters.end.ts"
            ],
            "settings":
            {
                "foreground": "#0000005e"
            }
        }]
    }
},
```

> Change the "[Visual Studio Light]" ti the name of the theme you are using.
>
> Change the "foreground" to any color you like.
>
> You can add and remove scopes.
>
> You can find out the scopes of text in vscode by opening the command pallet, then chose `Developer:Inspect Tokens and Scopes`, then click on the text you want to inspect.
>
> Screenshot:
>
> [image]